# Checking MySql for failed input to display

Tags: php

I am trying to update my code where I need to display what field of MySql errored. The script checks MySql and if the result ==0 based on passing 3 variables, then the $outstring will send the error in the $outstring. This $outstring is handled by jQuery using data.opp to determine error or success and displays the result in a dialog window. What is happening is that all my fields are being displayed in the $outstring where I am looking only to display which field failed.

What is the best way to proceed so I know which $variable is producing the 0 result and display just what part of the MySql failed. I have posted the relevant part of the code that handles this output. Many thanks.

```
<?php

$outString = ''; // NEED to do HTML output Formating on SERVER Side
    // Only Return a String to browser NOT an array


    foreach ($array as $box) {
        $box = mysql_real_escape_string($box);
        $sql = "SELECT custref,customer,department,status FROM boxes WHERE custref = '$box' ";
        $sql .= "AND customer = '$company' ";
        $sql .= "AND department = '$dept' ";
        $sql .= "AND status = '1' ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('{"opp":"error","box":"' . mysql_error() . '"}');

        // If there are no entries, send output to outstring as error
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {

            $outString .= $box . ' ';
            $outString .= $dept . ' ';
            $outString .= '1' . ' ';


    }   // foreach ($array
    }
    if ($outString) { // if there are numbers in this string, then there are error Duplicates
        $error = array('opp' => "error", 'box' => $outString); // box will have the TEXT for the Dialog Text
    // IMPORTANT, have changed JSON output to use an Opperation (opp) to indicate
    // in javascript if there was an error OR not
        $output = json_encode($error);
        echo $output;
        exit();
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're already checking the result of `mysql_query()` and using `mysql_error()` to get the error message reported by the database.  That should tell you what went wrong if the query fails.

Comment: When you say the "0 result", are you talking about the `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0` check?  That doesn't indicate a failure, at least not as far as the database is concerned.  It's not an error for a query to return no results.

Comment: @Wyzard If mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 that means somewhere in my query, the data is not validating. I need to know which variable or field is producing the ==0 condition. Thanks

Comment: It means you asked for data that doesn't exist.  You can't assume that the reason is because of a single field not matching — there might be no records with the specified customer *or* department.  There might be no records at all (i.e. the table is empty).

Comment: How do I quantify what the error is? Thanks

Comment: You can do a query looking for *just* the customer or *just* the department, to see if the user searched for something that doesn't exist at all.  But imagine that you have a record with customer "FredCorp" and department "Marketing", and you also have a record with customer "Joe's Pizza" and department "Delivery".  You do a query looking for customer "FredCorp" and department "Delivery", and get no results.  Is it because you were looking for the right customer but the wrong department?  Or the right department but the wrong customer?

Comment: Example, a user selects there department, item. My query is basically, if an item exists in that department and the status is '1' then return the results. However, what if they enter an item that isn't in that department or the status is not equal to '1', I need to display a message saying what part of there entry is incorrect. Is it dept or item or the status is not '1'. Thanks

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is, if a users inputs incorrect values, then display what values are incorrect.